# Error trying to use URLDownloadFileW

Tags: c++, c++builder-xe8

I'm trying to download a zip file from a link using the URLDownloadFileW function. The part of the code that I've developed by now with this function is:

```
UnicodeString URL = "URL.EX";
UnicodeString dir = "C:\";
UnicodeString result = URLDownloadToFileW(NULL,URL.c_str(),dir.c_str(),0,NULL);
if (result != "S_OK")
    return;
```

And I have declared the Urlmon.h on the header, however, when I build the project it returns me: 
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'URLDownloadToFileW' referenced from C:\USERS\ADMINISTRADOR\DESKTOP\SD MANUTENÇÃO\WIN32\DEBUG\SDSUPER449.OBJ
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
I'm not finding any usable search result about it. Does someone have any idea what does it mean?

Comment: did you add Urlmon.lib to linker options?

Comment: Also, `URLDownloadToFileW` does not return a string, it returns an `HRESULT` which is a number. You need to drop the quotes in your `if` statement: `if (result != S_OK)`

Comment: No, I didn't. Do I have to download it from somewhere? I'm using RAD Studio XE8, I was assuming it was already there...x.x

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 Tagging xD

Comment: I just double checked it, urlmon.h is a valid Lib in RAD Studio XE8. However it is behaving like there is no urlmon.h in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urlmon.h` is needed for the **compiler** to compile your code.  The compiler creates a reference to the `URLDownloadToFileW` function, but doesn't care where the function exists.  That is the **linker's** job to figure out.

`urlmon.lib` is needed for the **linker** to resolve the compiler's reference to the `URLDownloadToFileW` function.

RAD Studio has both files, in the `$(BDS)\include\win32\sdk` and `$(BDS)\lib\win32\release` folders, respectively.

You need to do both:

1. add an `#include <urlmon.h>` statement in the code.
2. link to the `urlmon.lib` file, by either adding the file to the project, or by referencing it in a `#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")` statement in the code.

You are missing step #2, which is why you are getting a **linker** error.

Comment: If I use #pragma, is the sintax: "#pragma comment(urlmon.lib)" right?

Comment: @Domicioli close, it is actually `#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")`

Comment: Just used : #pragma comment(lib, C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\lib\win32\release\psdk\urlmon.lib) but nothing changed :/

Comment: The quotes! ops

Comment: @Domicioli you don't need to specify the full path since the `psdk` folder should be in the IDE's library path.